# Angular 6 email regex

Tags: regex, angular

I want to validate all email inputs on my app with regex. But there is a problem, all the regex I have found allow emails with no TLD. I want a regex that can help me reject emails such as testing@testing,

Examples:

- testing@testing.com should be valid
- testing@testing.co.us should be valid
- testing@testing should not be valid

The current regex I use is : 
^([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})$

But it accepts testing@testing for example, and that is not what I want.
How would I go about validating emails and rejecting ones without TLD

Comment: Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: TLD list: https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db ; valid/invalid addresses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples ; regex for RFC822 email address:  http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the regex which does what you want:

`[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+\\.[a-z]{2,3}`

Comment: If you think this is a duplicate question, mark it as such and don't copy answer.

Comment: I have tried this in my Angular app and it fails to match any emails

Comment: Please create a stackblitz as I think the problem is not with the regex.

Comment: Please find the code here: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-edgene

Comment: Hi. I edited my earlier answer, now the regex will work.

Comment: I tried it and it works. What was the issue with the initial regex?

Comment: That regex was working on what are not allowed and this works on what is allowed. Actually Validation.pattern works internally I don't know so can't comment on that, but in normal circumstances that regex would have worked.

Comment: what about a regex for multiple emails?

Comment: By multiple emails, you mean inserting multiple emails in a single string. Can you please clarify.